# Linked list (invalid conversion from 'Node<int>*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]|) in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

This is a code I was facing problem while Inserting a new node in Linked List. I was getting error at line 73:

> [Error] invalid conversion from 'Node*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int x){
        data = x;
        next= NULL;
    }
};

void trans(Node *head){
    if(head!=NULL){
        cout<<head->data<<"->";
        trans(head->next);
    }
    
}

Node * insert(Node *head, int x){
    
    Node *n = new Node(x);
    n->next = head;
    return n;
    
}

Node * insertend(Node *head, int x){
    Node *temp = new Node(x);
    if(head==NULL)
        return temp;
    Node *curr = head;
    while(curr->next!=NULL)
        curr= curr->next;
    curr->next = temp;
    return head;
}

Node *del(Node *head){
    if(head==NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    else{
        Node *temp =  head->next;
        delete head;
        return temp;
        
    }
}

 int  search(Node *head, int x){
    int pos =1;
    Node *curr = head;
    while(head!=NULL){
        if(head->data ==x)
            {
             return pos;
             }
        else{
            pos++;
            head = head->next;
         }
         
     }
     return -1;
 }

Node insertPos(Node *head, int pos, int data){
    Node *temp = new Node(data);
    if(pos==1){
        temp->next = head;
        return temp;
    }
    Node *curr = head;
    for(int i =1; i<=pos-2 && curr!=NULL; i++){
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(curr==NULL){
        return head;
    }
    temp->next = curr->next;
    curr->next = temp;
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    Node *head = new Node(10);
    head = insert(head , 5);
    head = insert(head, 4);
    head = insert(head, 3);
    head =insert(head, 2);
    head = insertend(head, 6);
    head = insertPos(head, 4, 54);
    trans(head);
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<search(head, 4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your function definition for return type is Node insertPos should be Node* insertPos

Comment: Could you show the whole error message with the context? Are you expecting SO users should count the lines?

Comment: Also add keyword "explicit" to all constructors with one parameter. Otherwise the compiler might try to use such constructors as "type converters".

Comment: Repeating yourself to get around the warning that you are posting a badly written question does not change the fact that you have too much code for the amount of text. You should be willing to use more than one sentence to describe your problem and reduce your code to a [mre]. Syntax errors rarely need more than a dozen lines, usually no more than half that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Node insertPos(Node *head, int pos, int data)
```

Should be:

```
Node* insertPos(Node *head, int pos, int data)
```

Changing that shows terminal output of:
2->3->4->54->5->10->6->
3